# Cant see the image view in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im working on getting an image sent up to firebase. It works by selecting an image first, then the image being displayed and then finally you can click to send the image to firebase. I have it working but before I send the image off I can't see a preview of the image.

I want it to show the image ive selected in the image view.

thanks.

Here is my Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UploadImage">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChoose"
        android:text="Choose"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the class.

```
public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnChoose;
private Button btnUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
private Uri filePath;
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;

private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image);

    btnChoose = findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    btnUpload = findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();
    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chooseImage();
        }
    });
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
        }
        private void chooseImage()  {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select 
Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
        private void uploadImage()  {
            if(filePath != null)
            {
                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new 
ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
                progressDialog.show();

                StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ 
UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                ref.putFile(filePath)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
 taskSnapshot) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Uploaded", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                        .getTotalByteCount());
                                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null )
    {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have not pasted top line of your xml layout, can you post all xml file?

Comment: updated the xml @Khemraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnChoose"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Choose" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Upload" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

I seen low level code of choosing image in your snippet. You did not even compress image before using it.

I suggest you use some library for choosing image because they have already worked on compatibility with android api versions, permissions etc.

```
ImagePicker imagePicker = new ImagePicker(Activity.this);
imagePicker.setImagePickerCallback(new ImagePickerCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onImagesChosen(List<ChosenImage> images) {
            // Display images
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            // Do error handling
        }
    }
);
// imagePicker.allowMultiple(); // Default is false
// imagePicker.shouldGenerateMetadata(false); // Default is true
// imagePicker.shouldGenerateThumbnails(false); // Default is true
imagePicker.pickImage();
```

Just add `compile 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.31@aar'` to your app level `build.gradle`

Comment: Sadly not had any luck with that solution

Comment: Happily i could see your image having match_parent height in my AS.

Comment: If you can show your required UI then i can tell you way.

Comment: So i need to check your image chooser code. may be that's not working

Comment: above is all the code I have used. My chooseImage method is in there if that is what you are referring to?

Comment: I told you dude, your code is low level, i am not compiling your code to check errors. Just i can see it will create many run time issue in multiple devices. because you did not manage size of image received. So i suggested you use this library to choose image.